# why does sql server's datalength function double the length of my field?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datalength

I want to count the characters in an ntext field. [Following Pinal Dave's advice, I am using datalength](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/06/20/sql-server-find-length-of-text-field/). But this function seems to double the value I am looking for. When I copy the value in the field into word and count the characters, I get 1502. But when I do

```
select datalength(result) from myTable
```

I get a value of 3004 characters.

Why?

Comment: Unrelated - be careful of year(entrydate).  That can't use an index now.  While entrydate >= '2012-01-01' and entrydate < '2013-01-01'  would

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unicode is two bytes per character.  Your `NText` field is a Unicode string.  `DataLength()` returns the number of bytes required to store a field, `Len()` returns the number of characters.

From [`Len()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/len-transact-sql): "Returns the number of characters of the specified string expression, **excluding trailing blanks**." [`DataLength`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datalength-transact-sql) does not exclude trailing blanks. For Unicode strings you can use `DataLength( UnicodeStringExpression ) / DataLength( N'#' )` to get the length in characters.

In general `DataLength( Left( Coalesce( StringExpression, '#' ), 1 ) )` will return the number of bytes per character since [`Coalesce`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) returns a value based on [data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) where Unicode strings are higher precedence than byte-string types (`char` and `varchar`).

```
declare @Foo as VarChar(10) = 'Foo and ';
declare @Bar as NVarChar(10) = N'Bar and ';

select @Foo as [@Foo],
  Len( @Foo ) as [Len (trimmed)], DataLength( @Foo ) as [DataLength (bytes)],
  DataLength( Left( Coalesce( @Foo, '#' ), 1 ) ) as BytesPerCharacter,
  DataLength( @Foo ) / DataLength( Left( Coalesce( @Foo, '#' ), 1 ) ) as 'Characters';

select @Bar as [@Bar],
  Len( @Bar ) as [Len (trimmed)], DataLength( @Bar ) as [DataLength (bytes)],
  DataLength( Left( Coalesce( @Bar, '#' ), 1 ) ) as BytesPerCharacter,
  DataLength( @Bar ) / DataLength( Left( Coalesce( @Bar, '#' ), 1 ) ) as 'Characters';
```

Comment: if you want to know the length of a text field, you are stuck with datalength because len() wont work. So does that mean that you have to always have the datalength of the character (because unicode is 2 bytes per character).

Comment: @akh2103 - You simply need to divide the result of `DataLength` by two to get the number of characters.  You can divide by `DataLength( N'X' )` as a hint/reminder.

Comment: And `Len()` ignores trailing spaces.